# Updating an ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

I am trying to update my board (consisting of three arraylists in an arraylist) whenever a player inputs a number. The number corresponds to a square on the board in the following way:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

I am having trouble updating the grid.

**Function**

```
public static void playBoard(int choice, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> board, boolean playerTurn) {
    String val;
    if (!playerTurn) {
        val = "| X |";
    }
    else {
        val = "| O |";
    }
    if (choice>=1 && choice<=3) {
        System.out.println("H");
        ArrayList<String> updateRow = board.get(0);
        if (choice ==3) {
            val+="\n";
        }
        updateRow.set(choice-1, val);
        System.out.println(updateRow);
        board.set(0, updateRow);
        System.out.println(display(board));
    }
    else if (choice>=4 && choice<=6) {
        System.out.println("H");
        ArrayList<String> updateRow = board.get(1);
        if (choice ==6) {
            val+="\n";
        }
        updateRow.set((choice-4), val);
        board.set(1, updateRow);
        System.out.println(display(board));
    }
    else if (choice>=7 && choice<=9) {
        System.out.println("H");
        ArrayList<String> updateRow = board.get(2);
        if (choice ==9) {
            val+="\n";
        }
        updateRow.set(choice-7, val);
        board.set(2, updateRow);
        System.out.println(display(board));
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Input out of range");
        return;
    }
}
```

The problem is that when the user inputs a value, that entire column in which the value corresponds to is updated instead of the individual square.

I have checked that:

- Only one if statement is triggered.
- The update occurs only once
- The update occurs upon the correct index.

Through my debugging, I believe the problem line is:

```
updateRow.set(choice-1, val);
```

When the user (Player 1) inputs 1:

**Expected Output**

```
| X || - || - |
| - || - || - |
| - || - || - |
```

**Actual Output**

```
| X || - || - |
| X || - || - |
| X || - || - |
```

**Display function**

Sorry, I didn't realize you guys needed to see this other function

```
    public static String display(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> board) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (ArrayList<String> row : board) {
        for (String space: row) {
            builder.append(space);
        }
    }
    String text = builder.toString();
    return text;
}
```

Comment: Use a 2d array of fixed length [3][3] it would be easier to access, as you won't change the size (this is what List is made for)

Comment: Can you show your `display` method too?

Comment: On a first glance, your code seems to be fine although it could use some improvements. Show your `display` method, which might be the culprit.

Comment: I think you would be better off using a one-dimensional list, since you are already using indices 1 to 9. Would be way easier to manage

Comment: "I believe the problem line is: updateRow.set(choice-1, val);" No, definitely not. Your code is ok, It must be your mistake in displaying the final board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems in the creation: you probably used the same column ArrayList object for every row.

```
// Error:
ArrayList<String> row = new ArrrayList<>();
row.add("...");
row.add("...");
row.add("...");
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    board.add(row);
}
```

should have been:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    ArrayList<String> row = new ArrrayList<>();
    row.add("...");
    row.add("...");
    row.add("...");
    board.add(row);
}
```

The same conceptual error means: it is not needed to do:

```
board.set(2, updateRow); // Not needed.
```

Changing the entry in the updateRow object held by the board is done by reference.

Some tips:

- Here one can use `String[][]`.
- It is easier to separate display/view (the strings) from the data model (a char?),
  so maybe `char[][] board = new char[3][3];`

Answer (score 0):

I have used your code and added the display function and it is giving me the expected output. I guess you probably need to check the display function or the way you are creating the board. Below is the display function I used

```
 public static String display(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> board) {
     String output = "";
     for(ArrayList<String> list : board) {
         for(String s:list){
             output += s ;
         }
         output += "\n";
     }
     return output;

 }
```